# Row pagination with HBase

Tags: hbase

Is there a way to do pagination in HBase based on rowkeys?

I wanted to have the same effect as I do in `SQL with SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`.

If that's not possible, how should I best design my rowkeys to query appropriately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of **PageFilter** to do that. When you create the instance of PageFilter, you specify a **pageSize** parameter, which controls how many rows per page should be returned.

**Filter filter = new PageFilter(10);**

And if you wish to do it through the HBase shell you can use LIMIT with your SCAN query :

**scan 'table', LIMIT => 10**

Comment: And how do I get, say, from the 11th to the 20th row?

Comment: There is no way to do it by number.

Comment: I found out a way to do that sequencially using `PageFilter` as you said. To get the next set of rows, I get the last rowkey returned from the previous scan, then use it as a `starkey` in the second scan.

Comment: Wouldn't it be slow?For example if you want to fetch from 10000th row to 10010th row you have to pass through all the rows till you reach 10000th row and then get the actual 10 rows you need.

Comment: Well, true, I need to test it, but doesn't HBase has an index for the rows?

Comment: Nope. Row key is the only index of any sort in HBase. I'm still thinking if there is any better way to achieve this. Will let you know if I find some trick.

Comment: It would be really kind of the downvoter if could have the reason for downvote. A downvote without any reason/suggestion doesn't help in any way!

Answer (score -1):

What about using the ColumnPaginationFilter?

```
scan 't1', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.ColumnPaginationFilter.new(<count>, <start_offset>)}
```

Comment: ColumnPaginationFilter is for paging columns.. not rows