# How to achieve pagination in HBase?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, jersey-2.0

I am new to Hbase and I need to implement pagination using Java with Jersey and Hbase as my database. I need some help, how can I achieve pagination with Hbase as data will be distributed among various regions. I want to show 1000 records per page.

Please let me know how to achieve this without using any filter. It will be really thankful.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981450/row-pagination-with-hbase

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using the PageFilter present in habse filter. This will help you to get the paginated Rows from Hbase. There is a good article for pagination that you can refer to perform so. 
http://www.techsquids.com/bd/pagination-with-hbase/