# How to avoid some rows from scan object using pageFilter?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am new to Hbase, I am using PageFilter in HBase to scan 1000 records, while iterating through a **scan** object I want to exclude some rows based on rowkey(rowkey I will have), and then wants to apply a pagefilter on that scan object to read 1000 record by excluding the rows that I doesn't need. Is this be achievable??
Please let me know how can I achieve this, It will be really thankful.Thanks...

Comment: Ram, Is there any way to achieve backward navigation with Hbase for pagination??

Comment: [please note that that is cumbersome](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/tvn0YvxsOyg) thats [where I suggested Solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644997/how-to-achieve-pagination-in-hbase). We faced the same issue and addressed all issues with solr.

Comment: Rishi, Was my answer helpful? feel free to ask questions

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this through only Page Filter.
It should be combination can be like Fuzzy Row filter + page filter
as filter list to be passed to scan object.

> [FuzzyRowFilter(see hbase-the-definitive) This is really useful in our case](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hbase-the-definitive/9781491905845/ch04.html)
>   Which describes below....

FuzzyRowFilter
This filter acts on row keys, but in a fuzzy manner. It needs a list of row keys that should be returned, plus an accompanying byte[] array that signifies the importance of each byte in the row key. The constructor is as such:

```
FuzzyRowFilter(List<Pair<byte[], byte[]>> fuzzyKeysData)
```

The `fuzzyKeysData` specifies the mentioned significance of a row key byte, by taking one of two values:

> 0 Indicates that the byte at the same position in the row key must
>   match as-is. 1 Means that the corresponding row key byte does not
>   matter and is always accepted.
>
> **Example:** Partial Row Key Matching A possible example is matching partial keys, but not from left to right, rather somewhere inside a
>   compound key. Assuming a row key format of
>   _, with fixed length parts, where
>    is 4,  is 2,  is 4, and  is 2 bytes
>   long. The application now requests all users that performed certain
>   action (encoded as 99) in January of any year. Then the pair for row
>   key and fuzzy data would be the following:
>
> row key "????*99*????_01", where the "?" is an arbitrary character,
>   since it is ignored. fuzzy data
>   = "\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00" In other words, the fuzzy data array instructs the filter to find all row
>   keys matching "????*99*????_01", where the "?" will accept any
>   character.

An advantage of this filter is that it can likely compute the next matching row key when it comes to an end of a matching one. It implements the getNextCellHint() method to help the servers in fast-forwarding to the next range of rows that might match. This speeds up scanning, especially when the skipped ranges are quite large. Example 4-12 uses the filter to grab specific rows from a test data set.

Example 4-12. Example filtering by column prefix
    List> keys = new ArrayList>();
    keys.add(new Pair(
      Bytes.toBytes("row-?5"), new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }));
    Filter filter = new FuzzyRowFilter(keys);

```
Scan scan = new Scan()
  .addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("colfam1"), Bytes.toBytes("col-5"))
  .setFilter(filter);
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
for (Result result : scanner) {
  System.out.println(result);
}
scanner.close();
```

The example code also adds a filtering column to the scan, just to keep the output short:

Adding rows to table...
Results of scan:

```
keyvalues={row-05/colfam1:col-01/1/Put/vlen=9/seqid=0,
           row-05/colfam1:col-02/2/Put/vlen=9/seqid=0,
           ...
           row-05/colfam1:col-09/9/Put/vlen=9/seqid=0,
           row-05/colfam1:col-10/10/Put/vlen=9/seqid=0}
keyvalues={row-15/colfam1:col-01/1/Put/vlen=9/seqid=0,
           row-15/colfam1:col-02/2/Put/vlen=9/seqid=0,
           ...
           row-15/colfam1:col-09/9/Put/vlen=9/seqid=0,
           row-15/colfam1:col-10/10/Put/vlen=9/seqid=0}
```

The test code wiring adds 20 rows to the table, named row-01 to row-20. We want to retrieve all the rows that match the pattern row-?5, in other words all rows that end in the number 5. The output above confirms the correct result

***Another Approach***

You can also look in to RowFilter + page filters.
see [Example 4-1. Example using a filter to select specific rows](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hbase-the-definitive/9781491905845/ch04.html)

***Note : you can choose which ever is suitable to you***

Comment: Thanks Ram, but I want to ignore the set of row keys from my scan, but in case of FuzzyRowFilter it will take the set of rowkeys passed and will include those rowkeys to the result. Is their any other filter to ignore set of rowkeys from scan object..Thanks.

Comment: there is know part and unknown part for fuzzy row filter. so known parts of rowkey you can use tofilter rows in fuzzyrowfilter. please go through the link I have given completely. AFAIK, fuzzy row filter with paging will suit you. read complete example in the link for better understanding