# How can I query data from HBase table in millisecond?

Tags: redis, pagination, hbase

I'm writing a interface to query pagination data from Hbase table ,I query pagination data by some conditions, but it's very slow .My `rowkey` like this : `12345678:yyyy-mm-dd` , length of 8 random Numbers and date .I try to use Redis cache all `rowkeys` and do pagination in it , but it's difficult to query data by the other conditions  .
  I also consider to design the secondary index in Hbase , and I discuss it with colleagues ,they think the secondary index is hard to maintain .
  So , who can give me some ideas?

Comment: What exactly you mean by pagination data? Please provide example. In case of Hbase there is great deal about what conditions you use to query data unless you build separate indexes so provide examples of them too.

Comment: Sorry no examples, code is very long . And the secondary index just a idea,redis+hbase I've tried ,very well ,but  have some limitation .And  I just use Filter , you know if no datas be queried ,Hbase will scan all datas ,it's very slow .So I just want some ideas.

Comment: My answer might be useful for you, have a look.. feel free to ask questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, AFAIK random number + date pattern of rowkey may lead to hotspotting, if you scale with large data.

### Regarding Pagination :

I'd offer `solr` + `hbase` if you are using `cloudera` then its `cloudera search`. It gives good performance(proved in our case) while querying 100 per page and with webservice call we have populated `angularjs` dashboard.

Also, most important thing is you ***can move back and forth between pages*** with out any issues..

Below diagram describes that.

[image]

To achieve this,  you need to create collections(from hbase data) and can use [solrj](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) api

### Hbase alone with scan api doesn't work for quick queries.

Apart from that, Please see my answer. Which is more insightful with implementation details...

[How to achieve pagination in HBase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644997/how-to-achieve-pagination-in-hbase)

### Hbase only solution could be Hindex (co-processor based solution)

[Link](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/ApacheCon_hindex_0.pdf) explains more in detail

### Hindex architecture :

[image]

Comment: I have seen you answer , if I want quick queries must use the 3rd part ,?Example : solr or elasticsearch ..

Comment: YES  Solr or ES (may be I havn't tried) are good option, out of my experience with it. At poc level I tried different  options of Hbase client api including page filter and fuzzy row filter, none were up to my speed expectations. Further reference of available [options](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hbase-the-definitive/9781491905845/ch04.html)

Comment: Thx for your answer . I have suggested to use elasticsearch ,but leader disagree , him insist on using Hbase alone ,  and just want to use secondary index

Comment: one thumb rule of you want to go with hbase only solution. Always rowfilters are faster than column value filters(does full table scan to find out the values).

Comment: [hindex](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxnabjtdTOAhWDtI8KHeK3Da8QtwIINDAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DcIUNc08azYQ&usg=AFQjCNEgwceyvxd_bHt0W2mYGF8yxtmM4g&sig2=5aBIM645ZgeQy70DT0fx-w&bvm=bv.129759880,d.c2I) is another one which is hbase co-processor based solution.

Comment: please refer this to get more clarity on [huwei hindex](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/ApacheCon_hindex_0.pdf)

Comment: now the question is how can I get rowkey quickly in any condtions

Comment: If you have any further questions please feel free

Comment: Nice suggestion   ~

Answer (score 2):

In Hbase to achieve good read performance you want your data retrieved by small number of gets (requests for single row) or a small scan (request over range of rows). Hbase stores your data sorted by key, so most important idea is to come up with such row key that would allow it. 
Your key seems to contain only random integer and date so I assume that your queries are about pagination over records marked with time.

First idea is that in typical pagination scenario you access just 1 page at a time and navigate from page 1 to page 2 to page 3 etc. Given you want to paginate over all records for date 2015-08-16 you could use a scan of 50 rows with start key '\0:2015-08-16' (as it is smaller than any row in 2015-08-16) to retrieve first page. After retrieval of first page you have last key from a first page, say '12345:2015-08-16'. You can use it (or 12346:2015-08-16) to make another scan with start key 12346:2015-08-16 of 50 rows to retrieve page 2 and so on. So using this approach you query your pages fast as a single scan with predefined number of returned rows. So you can use last page row key as a parameter to paging API or just put last row key in redis so next paging API call will find it there.

All this works perfectly well until some user comes in and clicks directly to page 100. Or try to click on page 5 when he was on page 2. In such scenario you can use similar scan with nSkippedPages * 50 rows. This will not be as fast as a sequential access, but it's not a usual page usage pattern. You can use redis then to cache last row of the page result in a structure like pageNumber -> rowKey. Then if next user comes and clicks on page 100, it will see same performance as is in usual click page 1- click page 2- click page 3 scenario.

Then to make things more fast for users which click on page 99 first time, you could write a separate daemon which retrieves every 50th row and puts result in redis as a page index. Then launch it every 10-15 minutes and say that your page index has at most 10-15 minutes stale data.

You also can design a separate API which preloads  row keys for a bulk of N pages (say about 100 pages, it could be async e.g. don't wait for actual preload to complete). What it will do is just a scan with KeyOnlyFilter and 50*N results and then selection of rowkeys for each page. So it accepts rowkey and populates redis with rowkey cache for N pages. Then when user walks in on a first page you fetch first 100 pages row keys for him so when he clicks on some page link seen on page, page start row key will be available. With right bulk size of preload you could approach your required latency.

Limit could be implemented using Scan.setMaxResults() or using [PageFilter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/PageFilter.html).
"skip nPages * 50 rows" and especially "output every 50th row" functionality seems to be trickier e.g. for latter you may end-up performing full scan which retrieves the keys or writing map-reduce to do it and for first it is not clear how to do it without sending rows over network since request can be distributed across several regions.

Comment: First , thanks for your answer . I have thinked about my question and I found that maybe I mean was how can I get rowkey quckly .If I know the range of rowkey or single rowkey , Hbase will find datas more fast ,is it ? Ah , I have done it like your answer few days ago , but it wastes much time on find rowkey and count datas

Comment: Hbase stores data sorted by rowkey (plain bytes). So If you know which row keys you need to get (perform gets) or first and last row key of your result (perform first-row-key to last-row-key scan) then you have optimal way to access your data (via gets of single rows or via scan of a range for which you know start and end row keys).

Comment: Some other tricks with keys which come in mind:
1) range query when you know part of the key, like \0\0:2016-05-05 \FF\FF:2016-05-5 to get data for 2016-05-05
2) fuzzy row filter which can be used to retrieve partition of your result based on rowkey, e.g. something like scan with start \0\0:2016\0\0\0\0 and end \F\F:2017\0\0\0\0 and row filter mask xxx2016xx05 to retrieve only rows from  5th day of each motnth.
3) Putting information in columns, then using filters on them

Comment: And you can use KeyOnlyFilter to retrieve just a key, not row in your old solution if it's not there yet.

Comment: The question is what I don't know which row is I need . At this situation ,It  will spend a lot of time on find that row on the traditional way. So In my question ,I have said that I consider the secondary index which makes me get the start rowkey and the end rowkey(or single rowkey ) quickly ,but It's difficult to maintain

Comment: The KeyOnlyFilter ,I used .I know you mean ,it will need two steps to get datas ,first get the rowkey , then get datas by rowkey

Comment: Yep, I suggested to use \0\0:2016-05-05 in answer as a start key. If you know date which you need, then it will be enough to retrieve first page. When you retrieved first page, then you already know start rowkey for a second page and can put it in redis so when request for page 2 comes you will have this rowkey cached in redis. So you don't know even lower bound for first page? Or rowkey for second page is not coming  just after last rowkey in the first page?

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions and patience , I will consider your suggestions carefully , but just upvote  .  - - ||

Comment: BTW about row keys, you can design a separate API which preloads row keys for a bulk of N pages (say about 100 pages). What it will do is just a scan with KeyOnlyFilter and 50*N results and then selection of rowkeys for each page. So it accepts rowkey and populates redis with rowkey cache for N pages. Then when user walks in on a first page you fetch first 100 pages row keys for him so when he clicks on some page link seen on page, page start row key will be available. With right bulk size of preload you could approach your required latency.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for secondary indexes that are maintained in HBase there are several open source options (Splice Machine, Lilly, etc.).  You can do index lookups in a few milliseconds.